# Redirect error in post API

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, restify, passport-local

I am using node.js restify and passport module, restify-ensure-login module to perform user login authentication function.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-ensure-login

Here are the relevant code;

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new Strategy(
    function(username, password, cb) {
        db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return cb(err); }
            if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
            if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
            return cb(null, user);
        });
    }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
    db.users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return cb(err); }
        cb(null, user);
    });
});

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'myapp',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

var api_post_login = function (app) {
    function respond(req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('/');
        return next();
    }; //function respond(req, res, next) {

    // Routes
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }) );
} //var api_get_login = function (app) {

api_post_login(server);
```

The problem lies with `api_post_login()`. When this function is called at the login page when a HTTP post is performed to authenticate user name and password, an error appears as below;

```
{
     code: "InternalError",
     message: "res.redirect() requires a next param (function) is required" 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `passport-restify` instead of `passport`. So `npm install passport-restify`, and then change the require to `var passport = require('passport-restify');`